# Adding new column in gridview asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I need to add a new column for eg: district in the existing grid view.

But the district field values is based on city field which is already existing field in grid.

City to district maaping needs to be done dynamically.

Eg: City A,B,C are come under District D1.

Comment: try with RowDataBound

Comment: You should clarify the question.

Comment: can i add a new column without modifying datasource in grid view.for eg: district field is not there in database. But i need to add it in grid view. Is it possible?